# How to write reasonml binding for a union type

Tags: ocaml, ffi, reason, bucklescript, union-types

I am trying to write bindings for https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/blob/master/typings/react-native-keychain.d.ts#L76

getGenericPassword returns `false` if an error, else an `object` (`credentials`). I am not sure this union type can be represented in reason, but a better API would be the result an option (option(credentials)). But, how can I convert `Promise<boolean | credentials>` -> `Js.Promise.t(option(credentials))` in the binding file. Below is a template.

Thanks for your help.

```rust
[@bs.deriving abstract]
type credentials = {
  service: string,
  username: string,
  password: string,
};

/* TODO convert the actual return value 
Js.Promise.t(option(credentials)) to more reason type 
Js.Promise.t(option(credentials)) */

[@bs.module "react-native-keychain"] [@bs.scope "default"]
external getGenericPassword: unit => Js.Promise.t(option(credentials)) = "";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Js.Types.classify`](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Types.html#VALclassify) to get the runtime type of a value.

```rust
type maybeCredentials;

[@bs.module "react-native-keychain"] [@bs.scope "default"]
external getGenericPassword: unit => Js.Promise.t(maybeCredentials) = "";

let getGenericPassword: unit => Js.Promise.t(option(credentials)) =
  () =>
    Js.Promise.(
      getGenericPassword()
      |> then_(maybeCredentials =>
           switch (Js.Types.classify(maybeCredentials)) {
           | JSObject(obj) => resolve(Some(obj |> Obj.magic))
           | _ => resolve(None)
           }
         )
    );
```

Here `maybeCredentials` is defined and used as an intermediate type.

We then define a function with the same name as the binding, which will "shadow" the name and prevent the binding from being used directly in favour of our "override". However, *within* the override we're still able to use the binding.

We then call `Js.Types.classify` to get the runtime type of the returned value. If it is an object we use `Obj.magic` to cast the abstract `obj_type` to our `credentials` type (inferred from the return type of the function), and wrap it in an `option`. For any other type we return `None`.

By the way, this kind of "type" is called an untagged union. I've written down a few examples using different strategies for dealing with these, as both a producer and a consumer, in [bucklescript-cookbook](https://github.com/glennsl/bucklescript-cookbook#consuming-values-of-an-untagged-union-type).